# CallKit can reactivate sound after swapping call

Tags: ios, webrtc, callkit

I'm developing CallKit application, I have a problem, Call Holding is failing to restart audio when "swapping" calls on the CallKit screen until user returns to in-app call screen. I can bypass this by updating:

```
supportsHolding = false
```

but I can I solve this problem, whatsapp for example can do this correctly!

p.s. I'm using webrtc to make a call!

thanks!

EDIT:

This is code of provider:

```
public func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXSetHeldCallAction) {

    guard let call = conductor!.callWithUUID(uuid: action.callUUID) else {
        WebRtcConductor.debug("\(self.TAG)  failed to perform HeldAction: uuid: \(action.uuid), calluiid: \(action.callUUID)")
        action.fail()
        return
    }

    setIsHeld(call: call, isHeld: action.isOnHold)
    action.fulfill()
}
```

the setIsHeld function simply do:

```
audioTrack.isEnabled = enabled
```

If I use "mute" button of callkit screen, all works fine, but if I have 2 active calls, when I swipe from webrtc call to normal call, CXSetHeldCallAction is called and audio track did disabled, If I swipe again to webrtc call, audio track is enabled but i do not hear nothing, if I return to main app screen, audio works fine again!

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there is a limitation in the Google WebRTC Library which leads to the described problem when implementing a CallKit integration which supports swapping calls.

The [WebRTC Issue 8126](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=8126) is known for over a year now, but not yet integrated into the WebRTC master branch. However, you can find the necessary code changes to fix this problem in the original ticket.

However, as a workarround, you can trigger the system notification which is subscribed by WebRTC internally.

Post a `AVAudioSessionInterruptionType.ended` Notification in the "`didActivate audioSession`" method of the CallKit Provider:

```
var userInfo = Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>()
let interrupttioEndedRaw = AVAudioSessionInterruptionType.ended.rawValue
userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] = interrupttioEndedRaw
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.AVAudioSessionInterruption, object: self, userInfo: userInfo)
```

PS: Stare the ticket to improve chances of a merge ;-)

Comment: For Swift 4: `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification, object: self, userInfo: userInfo)`

Comment: Where should I use it? After fullfill?

Comment: @WorieN in 'didActivate audioSession'

Comment: Thanks you worked for me.
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didActivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
        print("Provider - Activate Audio Session: \(audioSession.category)")
        var userInfo = Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>()
        let interrupttioEndedRaw = AVAudioSession.InterruptionType.ended.rawValue
        userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] = interrupttioEndedRaw
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification, object: self, userInfo: userInfo)
    }

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. If I have 1 active call, then new calls is incoming, I tap hold&accept. New call works, but after using `Swap` in `CallKit` audio stops working.

Found that `provider:performSetHeldCallAction:` method from `CXProviderDelegate` protocol is the spot where you can actually deactivate/activate audio for `Swap` calls via `CallKit` native interface.

In my case I used the `audioController.deactivateAudioSession()` method for the call was putting in OnHold.
But found that the same method `provider:performSetHeldCallAction:` was fired for other call that is being put active (from OnHold state), when tap `Swap` button via CallKit.

So you just need to deactivate/activate audio respectively to call's state (either hold or not).

In common way it should look this way:

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXSetHeldCallAction) {
    // Retrieve the Call instance corresponding to the action's call UUID
    guard let call = callManager.callWithUUID(uuid: action.callUUID) else {
        action.fail()
        return
    }

    // Update the Call's underlying hold state.
    call.isOnHold = action.isOnHold

    // Stop or start audio in response to holding or unholding the call.
    if call.isOnHold {
        stopAudio()
    } else {
        startAudio()
    }

    // Signal to the system that the action has been successfully performed.
    action.fulfill()
}
```

P.S. It looks like you should have some class that responds for Audio session. It should implement kind of `activate audio session` / `deactivate audio session`.

Comment: This did not work in my case. I am also using WebRTC and set `audioTrack.isEnabled` to `false` (for both, local and remote track). This may have something to do how WebRTC processes audio internally. However, when forcing the App back in the foreground after swaping the calls (by pressing the "My App" button in the CallKit UI), audio is working again (both: incoming and outgoing - it's magic).